# Fails on GCP VM import precheck tool

Tags: google-cloud-platform, import

when i run the precheck tool in my centos linux:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/tree/master/cli_tools/import_precheck/

it prompts below, the disk check is failed.
any hints what approach to cater it? Thanks.

[fail message in gcp precheck too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiZpZ.png)

Sam Fok

Comment: The output tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/compute-image-tools/image-import.html#linux), you are installing multiple disks in which: Image import cannot directly handle multiple disk scenarios. Additional disks must be imported and attached separately. Also, the disk containing the OS must be bootable. The disk must be in MBR and have GRUB installed.

Therefore, you will have to make those changes in order to proceed.